# Could any vaccines be dangerous for people with G6PD enzyme deficiency?

Tags: side-effects, vaccination, deficiency

I have searched a lot, but didn't find an answer for this:

- Are there any vaccines that could be dangerous for people with G6PD enzyme deficiency?

About G6PD enzyme deficiency: http://www.g6pd.org/

Comment: please consider to suggest or edit proper tag with this question

Comment: I can't provide literature for this, but I can provide personal experience as both my brother, father and I are G6PD deficient. We have had no issues with vaccinations at all unless they are combined vaccinations. For example for me it was Typhoid and Hep A combination shot, I developed a severe reaction to the shot. My brother and father both react very badly to the quadrivalent flu vaccination. But I have absolutely no literature to back this up as there are very few studies conducted on G6PD deficiency and quadrivalent vaccinations. Overall though virtually no issues, just don't take anti-m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase (G6PD) is an enzyme that protects red blood cell against oxidative damage. G6PD deficiency is one the most common genetic disorders.

Most of the patients with G6PD deficiency remain clinically asymptomatic. However they are at increased risk of developing acute haemolytic anemia (AHA) in the presence of oxidative agents, which can be either fava beans, infections and drugs.

Considering that infection can precipitate acute haemolytic anemia, which can in some case have severe outcomes, vaccination would confer a solid way to prevent this.

The question asks about any contraindications for vaccinations in G6PD deficient patients.

Consulting the Vaccine Contraindications and Precautions provided by the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/admin/contraindications.html) did not mention G6PD deficiency as proven contraindications for vaccination. Additionally, a search in Medline (a biomedical literature referencing more than 26 millions citations from journals and online books) does not seem to provide any studies or case report concerning the occurrence of adverse events in G6PD deficient patient after immunisation either.

One study advocated hepatitis A vaccination in patient with G6PD deficiency in order to prevent damaging consequences from intravascular hemolysis precipitated by acute hepatitis A infection in two children with G6PD deficiency.

So far, there seems to be a lack of evidence against vaccination in G6PD patients. Like in many cases in medicine, the benefits of vaccination should be balanced with its possible adverse events.

Sources:

- Ozbay Hosnut F, Ozcay F, Selda Bayrakci U, Avci Z, Ozbek N. Etiology of
  hemolysis in two patients with hepatitis A infection: glucose-6-phosphate
  dehydrogenase deficiency or autoimmune hemolytic anemia. Eur J Pediatr. 2008
  Dec;167(12):1435-9.
- Youngster I, Arcavi L, Schechmaster R, Akayzen Y, Popliski H, Shimonov J, Beig
  S, Berkovitch M. Medications and glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase deficiency: an
  evidence-based review. Drug Saf. 2010 Sep 1;33(9):713-26.